# I want to provide a link to return the previous page on a 404

Tags: grails, http-status-code-404

I have an ErrorController that handles various application errors such as 404, 500, etc.  In these actions, I render appropriate error pages.  I would like to be able to provide a link on these error pages that takes the user back to the page prior to receiving the error.

I've tried getting the HTTP_REFERER header but it is always null.  request.forwardURI gives me the current request that is causing the error.

Suggestions?

```
class ErrorController {
  def notFound() {
    def backToPage = getPreviousPage // help here
    render view: '404', mode: [backToPage: backToPage]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [history.back() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp).

```
<script>
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back()
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```